# Determining if a field $f$ is conservative

Tags: vector-fields

So there is a question that I did where it made me find the integral of $f \cdot dr$ under the path $C$ (which is a semicircle when $x=0$ so $y^2 + z^2 = $) for the arc that connects $(0,0,-1)$ to $(0,0,1)$. For clarity, the function $f$ is $(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 , -z, y+1)$. I evaluated this to be $\pi + 2$. Now, it asks whether $f$ is conservative, and the answer says : "No, the line integral is dependent on the path". Now I know this is exactly the definition of a conservative field (that it is independent of its path), but how can we come to this conclusion?

I evaluated it for the path that forms the full circle which is non-zero, so it mustn't be conservative, but is there another way? How do we show it is path dependent?

Comment: A conservative force has a vector field which is irrotational (or has zero curl).

Comment: Isn't this only true under certain conditions?

Comment: A vector field with zero curl which is defined on the whole of the domain in question must be conservative. Since this function is defined on the whole of $\mathbb{R}^3$, it is enough to check that the curl is 0.

Comment: @Joppy Right. So if we had a vector field that had a component say $\frac{x}{y}$, then we cannot show that it is conservative based on the fact that it has zero curl?

Comment: @Paul Woch: That's right. However, you can still be sure that if that field had zero curl, any closed loop that doesn't encircle the undefined part will be zero. For example, if you were considering only paths in the region $x, y, z > 0$, then the vector field would be conservative there.

Comment: Ah I see. So this is a result because conservative fields only depend on the endpoints, so intuitively, the integral is independent of the path taken, so if there was a "hole" (like y=0 for that fraction), then picking a path through that "hole" wouldn't be defined, which is why it can't be conservative (because picking that path does indeed affect the integral)? Or am I overthinking this

Comment: @PaulWoch: No, it's no paths that go _through_ the hole (which should never be allowed), but paths that go _around_ the hole in an essential way which are the problem. It's similar to what happens when you're trying to calculate the winding number of a closed curve about a point: there is something fundamentally different (and discontinuous!) that happens for curves going "around" the point, than curves that do not. All of this is very related to notions of "simply connected" and so on, something that will be treated in any complex analysis or algebraic topology course.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, so in the example with the $x,y,z>0$, wouldn't a path containing say $(1,0.000001,1)$ be "around" the undefined part (and so it isn't conservative "around" there? You were talking about paths "around" the hole.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

It is conservative if

$$f_xdx+f_ydy+f_zdz=dU $$

or
$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)dx-zdy+(y+1)dz=dU $$

then

$$U=-yz+C_1(x,z) $$
and
$$U=yz+z+C_2(x,y) $$
which impossible.